# Inline pictures: Add margin

Tags: vba, ms-word, vsto, office-js

Is it possible in VBA or VSTO to add left/right margins to an **inline image**? I'm currently using <kbd>space</kbd> characters to create horizontal gap between two side-by-side inline pictures, but it is not accurate, since the width of space depends on font/style selection. I need a way of specifying the margin in points.

If there is a VBA/VSTO solution, can the same be achieve in Office.js too?

N.B. It is only the horizontal spacing that I need. Vertical spacing can easily be added using "Space After" feature.

Comment: No, there isn't a way of adding a margin to inline shapes. Have you considered using a table?

Comment: Yep. Tables is the last solution I'll go with if there isn't really another way. Can we control horizontal margin/padding using tables in Office.js?

Comment: Your only two choices are to use spaces or a table. I have no idea whether you can set padding in Office.js, you can in VBA.

Comment: AFAICS you may be able to add some blank space *on one side* of an image by changing InlineShape.PictureFormat.Crop.PictureOffsetX and/or InlineShape.PictureFormat.Crop.ShapeWidth, probably enough to separate two images, but you may have to save the original settings somewhere if you need to do further adjustments. It doesn't look to me as if you can change those property values via office-js yet.